# Mysql Sort price , when price thousand to K, million to M

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In a MySQL database, prices are stored in a way like this:

```
98.06K
97.44K
929.14K
91.87K
2.66M
146.64K
14.29K
```

when i try to sort price ASC or Price DESC, it returns unexpected result.

Kindly suggest me how can i sort price when price is in 
10K, 20M, 1.6B

I want result

```
14.29K
91.87K
97.44K
98.06K
146.64K
929.14K
2.66M
```

Comment: It's kinda weird to store prices like that, how is your database supposed to know what "K" and "M" is?

Comment: You store a price in a VarChar using this format? Don't do it.

Comment: I get prices from third party API, so i store it in VarChar, now i want to sort price.

Comment: Tell the third party to fix their code - numerical data should be stored numerically, and formatted only on output

Comment: And if you can't make them give you sensible data, you should convert the API data yourself _before_ you store it, and place it in an appropriate numeric column. Then sorting is easy.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL ignores trailing non-digits when casting string to numeric. This will return the correct price:

```
price * 
case right(price,1)
  when 'K' then 1000
  when 'M' then 1000000
  else 1
end
```

Of course, you can order by this, but you better apply it during load and store the price in a *numeric* column.

Comment: Don't you need to remove the K/M from price before multiplying?

Comment: @jarlh: MySQL simply scans the input and stops when there's a non-digit (or a 2nd `.`) without failing, strange, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed it is. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks, can you please suggest me full query? how can i use it, i try my best to apply this, but its return error "unexpected near right"

Comment: order by price return error, "unexpected near right"

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your data model. I understand that 2.66M is not necessarily exactly 2,660,000, which is why you don't want to store the whole number, but store '2.66M' instead to indicate the precision. This, however, is two pieces of information: the value and the precision, so use two columns:

```
mytable

value  | unit
-------+-----
 98.06 | K
 97.44 | K
929.14 | K
 91.87 | K
  2.66 | M
146.64 | K
 14.29 | K
```

Along with a lookup table:

```
units

unit | factor
-----+--------
K    |    1000
M    | 1000000
```

A possible query would be:

```
select *
from mytable
join units using (unit)
order by mytable.value * units.factor;
```

where you may want to extend the `ORDER BY` clause to something like

```
order by mytable.value * units.factor, units.factor;
```

or apply some rounding or whatever to consider precision of two seemingly equal values.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, though not advisable:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=0a837287c7646823fa6657706f9ae634

```
  SELECT *
       , CAST(LEFT(price, LENGTH(price) - 1) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS value
       , RIGHT(price, 1) AS unit
       , CASE RIGHT(price,1)
         WHEN 'K' THEN 1000
         WHEN 'M' THEN 1000000
         ELSE 1
          END AS amount
    FROM test1
ORDER BY amount, value;
```

Why not advisable? As the Explain in the dbfiddle shows, this query uses filesort for sorting, which is not very fast. If you do not have too many rows in your data, this should be no problem though.